# TypeError: Udefined is not a object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate') problema en react-native

Tags: react-native

tuve un problema al ejecutar mi código en reaccionar-native (he actualizado la última versión y pensé que el problema no era la actualización)
El problema proviene de cuando importo las bibliotecas de **react-navigation**
y quiero redirigir con un botón de App.js (archivo principal) a login.js (el archivo que quiero redirigir o abrir) el error viene cuando se coloca la siguiente línea de código

const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;

Esa línea se agrega para que la palabra navegar del siguiente código tenga sentido

onPress = {navigate ('login')}

Pero cuando escribo **const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;** me aparece el siguiente error

> TypeError: Udefined is not a object (evaluating
>   'this.props.navigation.navigate')

Mi pregunta sería cómo resolver este error.
De todos modos para que se pueda ver mejor mi problema dejo mi código.
Muchas gracias por cualquier respuesta.

Mi codigo:

```
//App.js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Image, Text, Button } from "react-native";
import { StackNavigator }from 'react-navigation';
import login from './login';


//const onButtonPress = () => {
//   Alert.alert('myapp');
//}

const App = StackNavigator({
    login: login,
});

export default class indextempo extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'myapp',
    };
  render() {
      const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
      return (
      <View style={styles.root}>
        <Image
          source={require("./files/images/fond.jpg")}
          style={styles.image1}
        />
        <Text style={styles.text1}>myapp</Text>
        <Text style={styles.text2}>myapp</Text>
        <Image
          source={require("./files/images/linkedin.png")}
          style={styles.image4}
        />
        <Image
          style={styles.image5}
          source={require("./files/images/facebook.png")}
        />
        <Image
          style={styles.image6}
          source={require("./files/images/google.png")}
        />
        <View style={styles.rect1}>
         <Button
             onPress={navigate('login')} 
             title="Entrar en la demo" 
             color="rgba(82,113,255,1)"
         />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  root: { backgroundColor: "white", flex: 1 },
  image1: {
    position: "absolute",
    width: 515.4,
    height: 868.18,
    top: -14.55,
    left: -18.5
  },
  text1: {
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    top: 57.95,
    left: 124.52,
    position: "absolute",
    height: 44.71,
    width: 110.94,
    fontSize: 38,
    color: "rgba(82,113,255,1)",
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  text2: {
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    top: 101.97,
    left: 73.02,
    position: "absolute",
    height: 19.54,
    width: 213.94,
    fontSize: 15,
    color: "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  image3: {
    position: "absolute",
    width: 81.94,
    height: 73.21,
    top: 307.68,
    left: 139.03,
    margin: "auto"
  },
  rect1: {
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    height: 40.79,
    width: 165.34,
    top: 550.81,
    left: 104.83,
    position: "absolute",
    borderWidth: 0,
    borderColor: "#000000",
    borderRadius: 100,
    opacity: 1,
    margin: "auto",
    },
  image4: {
    position: "absolute",
    width: 22.36,
    height: 22.53,
    top: 696.97,
    left: 336.72,
    margin: "auto"
  },
  image5: {
    top: 696.68,
    left: 313.01,
    width: 22.36,
    height: 22.53,
    position: "absolute",
    margin: "auto"
  },
  image6: {
    top: 696.4,
    left: 289.01,
    width: 22.36,
    height: 22.53,
    position: "absolute",
    margin: "auto"
  }
});

//login.js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Container,
  Header,
  Title,
  Content,
  Button,
  Item,
  Label,
  Input,
  Body,
  Left,
  Right,
  Icon,
  Form,
  Text
} from "native-base";
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class login extends Component {
  render() {
      return (
      <Container style={styles.container}>
        <Header>
          <Body>
            <Title>Myapp</Title>
          </Body>
          <Right />
        </Header>

        <Content>
          <Form>
            <Item stackedLabel>
              <Label>Nombre de usuario</Label>
              <Input />
            </Item>
            <Item stackedLabel last>
              <Label>Contraseña</Label>
              <Input secureTextEntry />
            </Item>
          </Form>
          <Button block style={{ margin: 15, marginTop: 50 }}>
            <Text>Iniciar sesion</Text>
          </Button>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
export default login;
```

*Gracias*

Comment: alguien podria ayudarme en esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/283258/react-native-invariant-violation-view-config-not-found-for-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu clase `indextempo` no existe la navegación por eso no tiene el prop de `navigation`

La solución sería declararlo en el StackNavigator

```
// Tu código
class indextempo extends React.Component {
    // Tu código
}

const App = StackNavigator({
    indextempo: indextempo, // Agregamos el index al StackNavigator
    login: login,
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @KacosPro por ayudarme a solucionar mi problema

Comment: Si la respuesta solucionó tu problema puedes marcarla como aceptada por si le sirve a alguien mas en el futuro :) Para mas información puedes ver [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)